# Need help shortening repetitive vb code

Tags: vb.net

I'm pretty new to programming, so this may be a pretty basic question. But, I need help to shorten this really repetitive code.
I'm working on a card game that has about 2 hundred different creatures, two decks (your and the enemy's), and 10 slots in each deck (meaning 10 creatures per deck).

In the deck builder part of my UI, when you actually add a creature to your deck, it does this:

```
If CritName = "Monarch" Then
    YourCreature1PictureDB.Image = DHBattleSim.My.Resources.Monarch_Icon
    YourCreature1Group.BackColor = Color.Transparent
End If
```

If the creature is "Ariel", then it'd be

```
If CritName = "Ariel" Then
    YourCreature1PictureDB.Image = DHBattleSim.My.Resources.Ariel_Icon
    YourCreature1Group.BackColor = Color.Transparent
End If
```

etc. Now, imagine there being two hundred of those statements, each for a different creature. THEN I need to copy that huge chunk of code, and change all of the 1's to 2's, and again, changing the 2's to 3's, etc. After I finish the 10's, I'd have to copy ALL OF THAT and change all of the "YourCreature" phrases to "EnemyCreature". So obviously this is extremely repetitive and tedious.
I know about the Find and Replace feature, but I'd rather shorten the code itself so that I don't have to resort to using that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use code like this

```
Dim resources As Object = DHBattleSim.My.Resources.ResourceManager
YourCreature1PictureDB.Image = resources.GetObject(yourVariable & "_Icon")
```

This,

```
YourCreature1Group.BackColor = Color.Transparent
```

can follow; in your original code it doesn't need to appear in every `if`, if it is always set to Transparent.

Answer (score 1):

create a sub for setting the image:

```
    Public Sub SetCreatureImage(critName As String)        
        YourCreature1PictureDB.Image = DHBattleSim.My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(critName + "_Icon")
        YourCreature1Group.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    End Sub
```